# Use of Status Groups EE2?

Tags: status

I have created channel 'History' and in Edit Group Assignments I have chosen 'None' as Status Group, though I am able to have option selecting Status during publish entries and am able to filter statuses with open and closed.

I would like what is the purpose of Status Group(None/Statuses) in channel Edit Preference??

Answer (score 1):

You can assign custom statuses by creating a status group. By default EE will always have Open and Closed statuses enabled even if you select none. The channel entries tag defaults to only show entries marked open by default and would not show anything if there was not a status assigned to the entry.